# Web app calling an other web app

Tags: python, angular, web-applications

i'm currently working on two different web apps, one in angular5 and the other one in angularJS/python with two different databases. My boss asked me to make a link between those apps, the databases doesn't need to communicate between each other. The best option for me would be to setup a button in the angular5 app which will call the other WebApp. I just have no idea of what's possible because i never used angular5 or JS.

So, in short, my question is how to navigate to another website with a button click event in Angular 5

Comment: Your question is far too broad.  I have no idea what exactly it is you are trying to do.  Is it possible to send an HTTP request from one web-app to another? Yes.  Is it possible to query a database from somewhere else? Yes.

Comment: There isn't enough information in this question to sufficiently answer the question without making a lot of assumptions.

Comment: Its interesting how people come to conclusions pretty soon, the answer is really simple, you need to link to another website in angular 5 on a button click!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that would be really simple
HTML:

```
<button (click)="redirectToAnotherWebsite()"></button>
```

Angular 5 component ts file:

```
redirectToAnotherWebsite() {
  window.location.href = "http://www.anotherwebsite.com"
}
```

That would be the simplest way, you have to do that in component since the html file doesnt know about window, anyhow, DON'T forget to put http:// or https:// since if you dont, it would just look for that link after your website's address like yourwebsite.com/thatLink. Cheers

Comment: Thx man that was exactly what i wanted i'm used to develop math algorithms i'm absolutely not a web dev xD

Comment: Great, trust me, it you are good with developing math algorithms, you will become a great web developer if you just spend some time! Glad to help, cheers brother!